# How to remove gogletab.com from Firefox/Chrome/IE in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-explorer

I have my system affected by gogletab.com new tab page virus which doesnt let me to use google.co.in in any browser (Firefox, Chrome, IE). It also generates and redirects me to some ad websites and third party spam websites.

Help me in removing this.

Methods Tried:

1. Browser addon checks
2. Reinstalled each browser
3. Register Clean up
4. Services clean up
5. Task Manager unwanted program clean up

Comment: Cleaning up unwanted programs in task manager won't be enough, as it's not the same as uninstalling them; likely the programs have just restarted themselves. Do you have any anti-virus software? Something like MalwareBytes or SUPERAntiSpyware.

Comment: I used some tools like Fixit and some other malware tools but those didnt pay off

Comment: Being general and telling us "some other malware tools" isn't helpful. What specifically did you use?

Comment: Tried out the methods mentioned over here https://www.pcrisk.com/removal-guides/10245-gogletab-com-redirect

Comment: From your list of stuff, I think no, you didn't follow the steps in this article.

Comment: I had completely tried out the article

Comment: From how thorough the article is, I sincerely doubt that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45465/discussion-between-sasikumar-and-kaizerwolf).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, You need to use an adware removal tool to remove gogletab.com,
which can detect every part of the hijacker nd uninstall it quickly
and cleanly.

Delete gogletab.com/en From Windows 10

- Right click on Windows 10 Start button and select the “Control Panel”
  option.
- Now got to the “Programs” category and click “Uninstall a Program” option.
- Select the gogletab.com/en from the list of installed programs.
- Finally Click on Uninstall or Remove button to delete the threat.
- Click on Yes button if Windows ask for confirmation.

Eliminate gogletab.com/en From Windows 8/8.1
Windows 8/8.1 users just follow the below steps to eliminate this nasty virus manually from your PC.

- At first drag mouse pointer and right-click edge at screen to get
  Quick Access Menu where need to choose search.
- Now Type Control Panel from list or right click at the bottom left
  corner (Start button) thereby to select Control Panel.
- Now click on Uninstall a program option after Control Panel Window get opened.
- After that, Programs and Features or Uninstall a Program screen emerged where you would view programs list as well as software, which currently installed on PC.
- Find gogletab.com/enthen press ‘Uninstall” after clicking on it.